# Getting two totally different results when I run Decision Tree Algorithm using normal accuracy and K Fold cross validation

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

The problem is I am getting two totally different results when I run the DTC algorithm, I just want to make sure that I am writing the cross validation - K Fold in a correct way or to understand why the result of the K fold is too much less than the normal one.

I've tried to run the codes for getting result from both normal accuracy and K fold accuracy the code is below:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas
from sklearn import preprocessing
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import pickle
import numpy
from pandas import Series
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
xx = pandas.read_csv("data1.dat", delimiter=",")
y = pandas.read_csv("label.dat", delim_whitespace=True)

x = xx.as_matrix()
y = numpy.array(y).astype(numpy.int)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)



clf2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict_2 = clf2.predict(X_test)
print("DTC Accuracy : ")
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict_2)*100)
```

DTC Accuracy : 
97.6302083333333

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
scores =cross_val_score(DTC, x, y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print(scores.mean()*100)
```

35.331452470904985

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
scores =cross_val_score(DTC, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print(scores.mean()*100)
```

97.34356

However, in the cross validation part, when I put X_train instead of x and y_train instead of y, the accuracy again rises to 97. 
I am wondering which one I need to use (x and y) or (X_train adn y_train) will be the correct and common sense cross validation.

Comment: Note that you aren't transforming X and y using the standard scaler while you are standardizing the train data.

Comment: @Guillem actually I tried to transform X and y and test it again, but it says the below 
"ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (191,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (191,2)" 
I am not sure, why it wants to add another colomn

Comment: If you only have around 200 instances you shouldn't be using cross validation on 10 folds, try to reduce folds to 3 or 4.

Comment: Even I reduced to 2 folds but still it is 50.2 percent. I am shocked of this, I was expecting that does not come to below than 90 percent, but now 40-50 will ruin everything

Comment: Maybe cross_val_score does not shuffle the data. Try to shuffle it. Also try to figure out why you cannot scale and scale it.

Comment: I don't know how to shuffle it separately and put in cross_val.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to shuffle your data and reduce the cross validation folds.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

xx = pandas.read_csv("data1.dat", delimiter=",")
y = pandas.read_csv("label.dat", delim_whitespace=True)

x = xx.as_matrix()
y = y.values.astype(np.int32).reshape(-1, 1)

x, y = shuffle(x, y, random_state=42)

DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
scores = cross_val_score(DTC, x, y, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
print(scores.mean()*100)
```

Comment: Very much thankful for this creative solution. Again, the accuracy raised to %95 for 10 folds. Thanks again